# Cordova admob is just showing test ads, not showing real ads

Tags: android, cordova, admob

> Admob real ads are not showing, It always shows "Test Ads" in both banner and interstitial.

I am using cordova js to build an android app which should be integrated with google admob.
I have searched and researched a lot in stackoverflow and youtube and google. **I have published the  app in to the google play store!**
I my previous version of app was built in cordova and working fine with admob ads. But in the new update of the app, admob always shows Test Ads.

**Note I have been waiting for 1 week from the app publish date**

Firstly I have created a cordova application and added android platform.

Then I installed the plugin using:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-admob-free

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID="ca-app-pub-6373615118835277~267935XXXX"
```

I have used the following code in my **index.js**:

```
var ShowBannerAd = function () {
    admob.banner.prepare();
            admob.banner.show({
                id: 'ca-app-pub-6373615118835277/846043XXXX',
                autoShow: true
            });
};

var ShowInterstitialAd = function () {
    admob.interstitial.prepare();
    admob.interstitial.show({
        id: 'ca-app-pub-6373615118835277/889395XXXX',
        autoShow: true
    });
};
```

In my **index.html**:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <button onclick="ShowBannerAd()">Show Banner add</button>
    <button onclick="ShowInterstitialAd()">Show Interstitialadd</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Is there any wrong use of codes I have used?**

**And How many days should I wait to see the actual ads in my app?**

**Will I have to wait always after a new update of my app?**

Thanks!
How can I show admob ads properly in my cordova application in easy steps?